# Empty first field when using multiple delimiters

Tags: awk, delimiter

I'm trying to parse the output of a program, which is given like this:

```
  Status       : OK (97 ms)
```

Those are all spaces, no tabs. I don't know if that spacing will remain consistent over different versions, so I want to treat spaces *and* colons as delimiters.

I'm well aware that the field separator can be declared as an arbitrarily complex regular expression, so I expect this would work:

```
echo "  Status       : OK (97 ms)" | awk -F'[ :]+' '/Status/{print $2}'
```

But it does not; instead it prints "Status", and `$1` is an empty string.

Compare this with the output of the built-in delimiter, where leading delimiters seem to be ignored and `$1` is "Status":

```
echo "  Status       : OK (97 ms)" | awk '/Status/{print $1}'
```

It's easy enough to print `$3` instead, but it makes me wonder what I am doing wrong, or misunderstanding?

I'm using GNU Awk 3.1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, in the sample input, field separators precede `Status`, the first field is empty and the second field is `Status`.  Observe:

```
$ echo "  Status       : OK (97 ms)" | awk -F'[ :]+' '/Status/{print $2}'
Status
$ echo "Status       : OK (97 ms)" | awk -F'[ :]+' '/Status/{print $2}'
OK
```

One option is to make `:` or `(` into field separators,  In that case, the second field will contain `$2` regardless of whether or not there is leading space:

```
$ echo "  Status       : OK (97 ms)" | awk -F'[:(]+' '/Status/{print $2}'
 OK 
$ echo "Status       : OK (97 ms)" | awk -F'[:(]+' '/Status/{print $2}'
 OK
```

Another option is to keep your field separator but eliminate the leading space before printing:

```
$ echo "  Status       : OK (97 ms)" | awk -F'[ :]+' '{sub(/^ +/,"")} /Status/{print $2}'
OK
$ echo "Status       : OK (97 ms)" | awk -F'[ :]+' '{sub(/^ +/,"")} /Status/{print $2}'
OK
```

#### Awk and leading or trailing field separators

For the default field separator, leading and trailing blanks are ignored.  If one uses a custom field separator, leading and trailing separator characters *not* ignored.  This is documented in the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html):

> 1. If FS is a null string, the behavior is unspecified.
> 2. If FS is a single character:
>
>    a. If FS is `<space>`, skip leading and trailing `<blank>` and `<newline>`
>      characters; fields shall be delimited by sets of one or more `<blank>`
>      or `<newline>` characters.
>
>    b. Otherwise, if FS is any other character c, fields shall be delimited
>      by each single occurrence of c.
> 3. Otherwise, the string value of FS shall be considered to be an
>      extended regular expression. Each occurrence of a sequence matching
>      the extended regular expression shall delimit fields.

Comment: That makes sense, but does not correspond with behaviour of the standard delimiter – see my edit above...

Comment: @miken32 That is true: as per the POSIX specification, the default `FS` is treated specially.  I added to the answer a quote from the POSIX that documents this.

Answer (score 1):

with your definition of the field separator, that's what the fields resolve to.  To visualize it better, let's replace the field separators with comma

```
$ awk '{gsub(/[ :]+/,",")}1' file

,Status,OK,(97,ms)
```

It's now clear that "Status" is field 2.